# Generating function of colouring a dodecahedron

Tags: group-theory

Find the generating functions in variables $r,b,g$ for the number of ways to paint a dodecahedron red,blue and green.

For example the coefficient of $r^5b^4g^3$ should be the number of ways to paint the dodecahedron with 5 red faces, 4 blue faces and 3 green faces.

I know that we should use Polya's enumeration theorem but I have no idea how to continue. Any solutions are appreciated.

Also it is allowed to be that r=0,or b=0 or g=0

Comment: IMO the key question is: Are two colorings considered to be different, if they are gotten from each other by a symmetry of the dodecahedron (a rotation, a reflection or a combination of the two)?

Comment: No they are considered to be the same @Jyrki

Comment: Nice autocorrect error! Poor Prof. Polyp!

Comment: Tommy, care to explain why you (or your namesake) asked this question again? This is a dup of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1393278/11619) asked by Tommy yesterday. It is against the rules to reask the same question. You should improve the older one instead.

Comment: I am closing this, because this was asked in bad faith.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be the symmetry group of rotations for the dodecahedron.
Following this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/381641/59379), we know
its [cycle index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index) is equal to

$$Z(G) = \frac{1}{60}
\left( a_1^{12} + 24 a_1^2 a_5^2 + 20 a_3^4 + 15  a_2^6\right).$$
It tells us the symmetry group $G$ consists of $60$ permutations:

- $\phantom{0}1$  permutation which is a product of twelve $1$-cycles. i.e the identity.
- $24$ permutations which is a product of two $1$-cycles and two $5$-cycles.
- $20$ permutations which is a product of four $3$-cycles.
- $15$ permutations which is a product of six $2$-cycles.

Let's say we are going to color the faces of a dodecahedron with $n$ colors $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n$.
[Burnside's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma)
tell us the number of ways is equal to

$$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} |X_g|$$

where $X_g$ is the set of colorings (by colors $c_1, c_2, \ldots c_n$ ) invariant under the action of $g$.

Consider the case $g$ is a product of $m$ disjoint cycles of length $\ell_1, \ell_2, \ldots, \ell_m$ with $\sum_{j=1}^m \ell_j = 12$.
If a coloring is invariant under $g$, then every face belongs to same cycle
need to have same color. The $j^{th}$ cycle of length $\ell_j$ will contribute a
factor $c_1^{\ell_j} + c_2^{\ell_j} + \cdots + c_n^{\ell_j}$ to the GF.

This leads to one simplified variant of
[Pólya enumeration Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem#The_full.2C_weighted_version):

> To compute the generating function for $n$ colors $c_1, c_2, \cdots, c_n$,
>   replace every appearance of $a_k$ in the cycle index by $c_1^k + c_2^k + \cdots + c_n^k$.

Apply these to the case of $3$ colors $r, g, b$, the generating function
we seek is given by

$$\frac{1}{60}
\left( (r+g+b)^{12} + 24 (r+g+b)^2 (r^5+g^5+b^5)^2 \\+ 20(r^3+g^3+b^3)^4 + 15  (r^2+g^2+b^2)^6\right)$$

Comment: +1 This passes the obvious lithmus test that the coefficients of all monomials are integers. I checked that with Mathematica (that's how I spotted that one small typo).